# Fail to implement the pmf model in pystan

Tags: python, stan

I am a newbie to both stan and machine learning. Now I'd like to implement the pmf model. Here is part of my code:

```
pmf_cod="""
data {

int<lower=0> K; //number of factors
int<lower=0> N; //number of user
int<lower=0> M; //number of item
int<lower=0> D; //number of observation
int<lower=0> D_new; //number of pridictor 
int<lower=0, upper=N> ii[D]; //item 
int<lower=0, upper=M> jj[D]; //user
int<lower=0, upper=N> ii_new[D_new]; // item
int<lower=0, upper=N> jj_new[D_new]; // user
real<lower=0, upper=5> r[D]; //rating
real<lower=0, upper=5> r_new[D_new]; //pridict rating

}

parameters {
row_vector[K] i[M]; // item profile
row_vector[K] u[N]; // user profile
real<lower=0> alpha;
real<lower=0> alpha_i;
real<lower=0> alpha_u;

}

transformed parameters {
matrix[N,M] I; // indicator variable
I <- rep_matrix(0, N, M);
for (d in 1:D){
    I[ii[d]][jj[d]] <- 1;
}
}

model {
for (d in 1:D){
    r[d] ~ normal(sum(u[jj[d]]' * i[ii[d]]), 1/alpha);
}

for (n in 1: N){
    u[n] ~ normal(0,(1/alpha_u) * I);
}
for (m in 1:M){
    i[m] ~ normal(0,(1/alpha_i) * I);
}
}
"""
```

But I got a error:`No matches for: row vector ~ normal(int, matrix)` in this line of code:

```
for (n in 1: N){
    u[n] ~ normal(0,(1/alpha_u) * I);
}
```

Where `I` is a unit matrix. So the product of `(1/alpha_u) * I` is also a matrix. But stan just accept vector or real value as variance. I wonder how to transform it to a vector or a single value.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiply two 1\*k vectors but got No matches for: real ~ normal(matrix, real) error in pystan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296429/multiply-two-1k-vectors-but-got-no-matches-for-real-normalmatrix-real-err)

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you intend to be using the *multivariate* normal density, in which case the function you are looking for is `multi_normal` rather than `normal`. However, the `multi_normal` function needs a mean vector as its first argument, so you would need to call it as

`u[n] ~ multi_normal(rep_vector(0, K), (1/alpha_u) * I);`

In addition, there is no need to create `I` in the `transformed parameters` block when it should be created in the `transformed data` block.

All that said, you should never use the `multi_normal` density in Stan when the variance-covariance matrix is diagonal. Under this assumption, the multivariate normal distribution factors into a product of univariate normal distributions, so you would be better off doing

`u[n] ~ normal(0, 1 / alpha_u);`